# Why/How to use passed constants in function?

Tags: coding-style, constants

I've seen classes where constants are passed to methods, I guess its done to define some kind of setting in that function. I cant find it anywhere now to try to find out the logic, so I though I could ask here. How and why do you use this concept and where can I find more information about it?

The example below is written in PHP, but any language that handles constants would do I guess..

```
// Declaring class
class ExampleClass{
  const EXAMPLE_CONST_1 = 0;
  const EXAMPLE_CONST_2 = 1;  

  function example_method($constant(?)){

     if($constant == ExampleClass::EXAMPLE_CONST_1)
       // do this
     else if($constant == ExampleClass::EXAMPLE_CONST_2)
       // do that

  }
}

// Using class
$inst = new ExampleClass();
$inst->example_method(ExampleClass::EXAMPLE_CONST_1);
```

To me its more clear to pass "ExampleClass::EXAMPLE_CONST_1" than to just pass "1", but it's that the only reason to pass constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply passing 1 doesn't say much. By having a constant you can have a description about the settings in the name.

example:
constant RAIN = 1;

method setWeather(RAIN);

Atleast that's how and why I use it.

Comment: Ok :) Do you know any source for anymore information on this?

Comment: No sorry, I just remember this from school :)

Comment: See Robert Martin's [elaboration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/0132350882) on Fowler's "Code smells": "G25: Replace Magic Numbers with Named Constants"

Comment: Found this, google "replace magic numbers with" and youll find alot. http://css.dzone.com/articles/practical-php-refactoring-12

Answer (score 1):

It is always a good idea to avoid literals being passed around. By assigning a *name*, anyone reading your code has a chance to understand what that value means - a number has no meaning. It might also help you maintaining your code: If for some requirement the value has to be changed, you can easily do it in one place, instead of checking each and every value occurrence.