# why do they always use number as return code?

Tags: protocols

once i setup a project ,i need set codes to describe the operations result which return to client.

so the code be like these:

```
100 'succeed 
200 'failed
201 'failed because the require object doesn't exist
...
```

or like these:

```
43100 'shop buy item succeed
43201 'shop buy item failed because user doesn't have enough money
43202 'shop buy item failed because the item sold out.
...
```

but in real development,the return code thing didn't go well, teammates must use dictionary to look up what's the meaning of a code.nobody remember any of them.

so i thought why must we use number as return code? only because in our experience many protocols return digital code ,like the most famous http protocol 404,403,500,etc..

so  my question is why they use number?isn't string is better for human reading?
like 'FileNotFound' replace 404. or 'success.cart.order' which means in module 'cart' sub function 'order' the operation is success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I do not know the definitive answer. For software, however, numbers have a few advantages:

- Integral number processing is faster than string processing and numbers need less storage for messages (both in memory or over a wire).
- Numbers have allowed you to use `switch` / jump-tables for decades (faster processing too).
- Typos are less subtile with numbers. You are less likely to make mistakes like using `FileNotfound` instead of `FileNotFound`.
- In memory string tend to be stored in a lot of different ways. I guess numbers reduce interoperability issues, too.

Answer (score 1):

Human readability is only one aspect, in most cases you will also need to *process* operations results. Performing String comparisons is error prone and unnecessarily costly. Recently, someone asked about [using constant values instead of literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384592), and this is how you can achieve readability: By using well-named constants for all of your return codes. I like to use `Enum`s for this task, yet this is not possible in all programming languages.

Comment: use what code maybe really depend on what language you use,in our case we use python and actionscript,handle textual code isn't a big problem, and i think in most modern main stream language , it would be ok.

Comment: Enums have the advantage that you can bundle constants and (human readable) text in one place.

Answer (score 1):

Because frequently, the thing receiving the status code is *another* piece of code.

Having to parse a string message (that may vary based on language settings, or because a developer chose to improve the wording in a later release) may be quite complex.

And in many situations, you can return a numeric code *and* a message - one's intended for code to consume, the other is for the human beings.

Comment: we just did what you tell in the last paragraph , but unfortunately you still need the dictionary ,because the process is based on the code.